# Web post with encoding issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, decode

Everything was working fine – we get inbound text messages and this webpage accepts the call – parses out the data and then inserts into our database – a few days ago they started sending SOME of the url calls with a different encoding and now when it’s parsed there are odd characters in the string

Even the clickatell website when looking at the message on their reports - doesn't display properly - it inserts funky characters between each letter of the text.  Assuming this is because end users are sending emoticons or something like that.

URL Call being sent to us –

http://website/clickatell.aspx?api_id=3360511&from=12173726674&timestamp=2018-01-24%2019%3A16%3A54&text=%00I%20%19%00m%00%20%00p%00e%00r%00m%00%20%00r%00i%00g%00h%00t%00%20%00n%00o%00w%00.%00%20%00B%00u%00t%00%20%00i%00f%00%20%00I%00%20%00s%00t%00a%00r%00t%00%20%00t%00r%00a%00v%00e%00l%00i%00n%00g%00%20%00a%00g%00a%00i%00n%00%2C%00%20%00I%20%19%00l%00l%00%20%00c%00o%00n%00t%00a%00c%00t%00%20%00y%00o&charset=UTF-16BE&udh=050003110201&moMsgId=a15c4039887a22425e9c42b86f6ddca4&to=17752374422

Normal URL call -

http://website/clickatell.aspx?api_id=3360511&from=15204455150&timestamp=2018-04-17%2019%3A17%3A05&text=Okay.%20I%27ll%20post%20it%20up%20in%20a%20bit.%20&charset=ISO-8859-1&udh=&moMsgId=f1690c98ff631db19ef26e619fd6f9e4&to=17752374422

ASPX Code (.Net 3.5) the If looks for the new encoding charset and executes the IF

```
    if (Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("UTF-16BE") > 0)
    {
        if (Request["api_id"] != null) sAPIId = Server.UrlDecode(Request["api_id"]);
        if (Request["moMsgId"] != null) sMsgId = Server.UrlDecode(Request["moMsgId"]);
        if (Request["from"] != null) sSource = Server.UrlDecode(Request["from"]);
        if (Request["to"] != null) sTarget = Server.UrlDecode(Request["to"]);
        if (Request["udh"] != null) sHeader = Server.UrlDecode(Request["udh"]);
        if (Request["text"] != null) sText = Server.UrlDecode(Request["text"]);

    }
    else
    {
        if (Request["api_id"] != null) sAPIId = Request["api_id"];
        if (Request["moMsgId"] != null) sMsgId = Request["moMsgId"];
        if (Request["from"] != null) sSource = Request["from"];
        if (Request["to"] != null) sTarget = Request["to"];
        if (Request["udh"] != null) sHeader = Request["udh"];
        if (Request["text"] != null) sText = Request["text"];
    }
```

UrlDecode results in this – I’m sure there is an easy way to get from the hex encoding above to just a plain string – but I can’t seem to track it down.

"\0I _\0m\0 \0p\0e\0r\0m\0 \0r\0i\0g\0h\0t\0 \0n\0o\0w\0.\0 \0B\0u\0t\0 \0i\0f\0 \0I\0 \0s\0t\0a\0r\0t\0 \0t\0r\0a\0v\0e\0l\0i\0n\0g\0 \0a\0g\0a\0i\0n\0,\0 \0I _\0l\0l\0 \0c\0o\0n\0t\0a\0c\0t\0 \0y\0o"

Also tried Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Request.Url))) – but gave same result

Comment: That looks like UTF16 bytes decoded as ASCII, then URL-encoded.

Comment: It clearly says &charset=UTF-16BE in the URL.  That's UTF-16 big endian.

Comment: I get that now - but how do you get it from the URL string and converted out to just plain text.